# generating a variable in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to generate PMdist`i' variables, using the following codes

```
display "************** PM10 distances **************"


forval i=1/12599 {
    display "Attempting to compute distance `i'"

    capture geodist latitude longitude latitude`i' longitude`i' [if] [in], generate(PMdist`i')

    capture replace PMdist`i' = . if (PMdist`i' > 257 & !missing(PMdist`i'))

    capture drop latitude`i' longitude`i'
  }
egen PMmindist = rowmin(PMdist1-PMdist12581)

forval i=1/12599 {

    capture drop PMdist`i'
}
```

Can anyone tell me why geodist is not working and what is the alternative solution?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? This could be slow, but is there another problem? Why 12599 in some places and 12581 in others? Not enough information here to offer precise help. The code should be tested on a trivial dataset first.

Comment: I am replicating this data code (used by author) by  using the same dataset the author used. When I run it cannot generate PMdist`i' variable, and when I ran another code that require to use PMdist'i' variable, the error shows 'cannot find Pmdist`i' variable.

Comment: I would start by removing your `capture` commands. There's probably a problem with the `geodist` command but you cannot spot it when you use `capture`.

Comment: Probably one or several of your long/lat(`i') variables don't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Many Stata commands allow optional `if` or `in` conditions. That they are optional is denoted in the help files by square brackets. However, these square brackets should not be used when calling the actual command.

In your case, you don't seem to be needing `if` or `in` conditions so you can just get rid of them entirely.

```
capture geodist latitude longitude latitude`i' longitude`i', generate(PMdist`i')
```

Comment: I  tried without [in] [if]  as well. But still it can't generate that variable. Later I added [if] [in] but it does not make any change